# Move a menu with the entire page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to know how to make menu button fixed at page top. I need it to be available whenever page scroll down or up. On click; menu should slide down. Thank you to everyone who will answer and sorry for my bad english. PS Even if in this platform the menu is not shown well, in my website it works fine, just is stuck only on the top left corner and doesn't move with the page

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".cross").hide();
    $(".menu").hide();
    $(".hamburger").click(function() {
        $(".menu").slideToggle("slow", function() {
            $(".hamburger").hide();
            $(".cross").show();
        });
    });

    $(".cross").click(function() {
        $(".menu").slideToggle("slow", function() {
            $(".cross").hide();
            $(".hamburger").show();
        });
    });
});
```

```css
header {
    width: 100%;
    background: #ffffff;
    height: 0px;
    line-height: 0px;
    border-bottom: 0px solid #dddddd;
}

.hamburger {
    background: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    line-height: 45px;
    padding: 5px 15px 0px 15px;
    color: #ffffff;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 2.0em;
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor: pointer;
    outline: none;
    z-index: 10000000000000;
}

.cross {
    background: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    padding: 5px 15px 0px 15px;
    color: #ffffffff;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 4em;
    line-height: 55px;
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor: pointer;
    outline: none;
    z-index: 10000000000000;
}

.menu {
    z-index: 1000000;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    width: max(20%, max-content);
    background: #666;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 10px;
}

.menu ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    list-style-image: none;
}

.menu li {
    display: block;
    padding: 15px 0 15px 0;
}

.menu li:hover {
    display: block;
    background: #666;
    padding: 15px 0 15px 0;
    border-bottom: #666 10px solid;
}

.menu ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: 0px;
    color: #666;
    letter-spacing: 5px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font: 13px "Lato", sans-serif;
    color: #111;
    text-align: center
}

.menu ul li a:hover {
    color: #666;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.menu a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 5px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font: 13px "Lato", sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
}

.menu a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 5px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font: 15px "Lato", sans-serif;
    text-align: center
}

.glyphicon-home {
    color: black;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<header>
<button class="hamburger">&#9776;</button>
        <div class="menu">
            <ul>
                <li><button class="cross">&#735;</button></li>
                <a href="#g1">
                    <li>Link 1</li>
                </a>
                <a href="#g2">
                    <li>link 2</li>
                </a>
                <a href="#g3">
                    <li>link 3</li>
                </a>
                <a href="#g3">
                    <li>link4</li>
                </a>
            </ul>
        </div>
       </header>
```

Comment: do you mean by moving, is when you scroll at the page, menu will be at there position ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to fix its position.

```
position: fixed;
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Which tag i have to fix with fixed? Every absolute? Or every menu tag ?

Comment: It's unclear to me what exactly you're trying to have move, but I would assume it's the hamburger menu? in which case change the header tag.

Comment: Yeah exactly is the hamburger menu, Sorry for being not clear. So now the answer is, how Can i position to fixed the header? Assignin It an id?

Comment: Just add "position:fixed;" under "header" in your CSS

Answer (score 0):

Your code need to rebuild. You have a lot of code with no need. HTML Structure is not correct.

As @eric mentioned. you should use fixed position.

I made some changes to your code. Check it out at:

```
header {
    background: red;
    height: 1000px;
}

.menu {
  position: fixed;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  z-index: 999999;
}

.menu button {
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
  color: white;
  font-size: 18px;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 5px 15px;
}

.menu button:hover {
  background: #fff;
  color: black;
}

.menu ul {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    display: none;
}


.menu ul li a {
    display: block;
    letter-spacing: 5px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font: 13px "Lato", sans-serif;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 15px 5px;
}

.menu ul li a:hover {
    background: white;
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pKyNEJ